# Halos on images taken with a Panasonic Lumix DMC-FS35

Tags: autofocus, image-quality, panasonic

Every image I take with my DMC-FS35 shows a halo around the subject. (See below) This is true in all light conditions with or without flash.

INSERT IMAGE HERE

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample of what you mean?

Comment: (Can someone lend another up vote so Pete can post images?)

Comment: done - images please!

Comment: It is very possible Pete will never return. Lot of times we get new users who ask a question, never to see the answers or accept/vote them. Hopefully he will, he's got six upvotes now...but I wouldn't recommend anyone hold their breath yet. :P

Comment: Closed this since the user is not registered and hasn't been back since basically asking this question.